# Rails CSS not Loading using Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, heroku, haml

> **UPDATE**: The full site code is here - https://github.com/eWizardII/PeerInstruction

I have the following site set up here on Heroku - http://www.peerinstruction.net/users/sign_up the issue is that I have updated the css yet it is not being actively reflected on the site, it just shows a textbox, with some edited/custom fonts. I have attached the css file in the following gist - https://gist.github.com/f74b626c54ecbb60bbde

The signup page controller:

```
!!! Strict
%html
  %head
    %title= yield(:title) || "Untitled"
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', 'web-app-theme/base', 'web-app-theme/themes/activo/style', 'web-app-theme/override'
    = javascript_include_tag :defaults
    = csrf_meta_tag
    = yield(:head)
  %body
    #container
      #header
        %h1
          %a{:href => "/"} Peer Instruction Network
        #user-navigation
          %ul.wat-cf
            %li
              .content.login
                .flash
                  - flash.each do |type, message|
                    %div{ :class => "message #{type}" }
                      %p= message
                = form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :html => { :class => "form login" }) do |f|
                  .group.wat-cf
                    .left= f.label :email, :class => "label right"
                    .right= f.text_field :email, :class => "text_field"
                  .group.wat-cf
                    .left= f.label :password, :class => "label right"
                    .right= f.password_field :password, :class => "text_field"
                  .group.wat-cf
                    .right
                      %button.button{ :type => "submit" }
                        Login
              /= link_to "Sign In", destroy_user_session_path
      #box
        = yield
```

The signup pages haml file:

```
%h2
.block
  .content.login
    .flash
      - flash.each do |type, message|
        %div{ :class => "message #{type}" }
          %p= message
      = form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
        = devise_error_messages!
        %div
          = f.label :firstname
          %br/
          = f.text_field :firstname
        %div
          = f.label :middlename
          %br/
          = f.text_field :middlename
        %div
          = f.label :lastname
          %br/
          = f.text_field :lastname
        %div
          = f.label :email
          %br/
          = f.email_field :email
        %div
          = f.label :password
          %br/
          = f.password_field :password
        %div
          = f.label :academic
          %br/
          = f.text_field :academic
        %div= f.submit "Continue"
      = render :partial => "devise/shared/links"
```

I used web-app-theme to create an activo theme and then modify it.

Comment: What happens if you run localhost in production environment? Also, as has been pointed out, your base.css if full of [invalid chars](http://www.peerinstruction.net/assets/web-app-theme/base-616e90278074713561d38749e5d5d938.css).

Comment: PS - the highlighting on the whitespaces in your [Gist](https://gist.github.com/f74b626c54ecbb60bbde) indicate that something is wrong with it too. Perhaps Heroku is rejecting it when you push it? Did you paste this in from Word? It's best to paste from Notepade or something that strips format

Comment: Well looking at the css on Chrome the actual file is full of invalid characters despite it not containing any when I use Chrome's inspection tool - http://www.peerinstruction.net/assets/web-app-theme/base.css

Comment: Some how I can delete the folder web-app-theme on my local folder, and it still manages to find the files when I do rails server - I don't know why, but I think that's part of the problem.

Comment: I see now that the style has changed a bit and there are no more invalid chars. Is this resolved? If not, do you have an image of what you expect your app to look like? You could always stick the code on github if you don't mind people looking at it

Comment: Thanks - I just set it up on github - https://github.com/eWizardII/PeerInstruction

Comment: OK, I will take a look in moment, but you definitely want to remove your S3 file from config folder as it contains sensitive data and you don't want that on github. I'd recommend changing your S3 credentials before someone goes and copies them down.

Comment: Thanks, working on removing it - to a new repo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is your [working app](http://warm-mist-7080.herokuapp.com/users/sign_up)

I had to do a few things to fix it.

Firstly, I put it on cedar stack, that's important.

Then, it's vital to change your Gemfile. I made a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/1379228) of what I did there but in short I moved sqlite3 into dev and test envs, and I removed the rubyracer gem.

I think that's all I did.

I'd get into the habit of removing compiled assets that are no longer being used by the way, as they will just take up loads of space in `public/assets`

Comment: ps, I've left a few comments in the Gist, and if you don't have any luck, delete the app from heroku, create a new one on cedar `heroku create --stack cedar`, push and migrate

Comment: Cool, thanks alot! Also turns out one of the other issues - was I think the designer copied the css non-plain text, as I noticed an older css file they sent it didn't have that problem which is the one I put in the override at present.

Answer (score 2):

I [validated your css](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.peerinstruction.net%2Fusers%2Fsign_up&profile=css21&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en) and it comes up with lots of warnings about invalid properties.

I suspect it is some sort of character set mismatch between what is being served and what is in the document. Because of the CSS not parsing, none of the CSS will work.

Comment: Thanks my only issue is that on the local host it loads some of the css - or it doesn't atleast appear like a plane screen, like it does when I push to heroku.

Answer (score 2):

Few problems, overide.css is not is not found. You have a 404:

http://www.peerinstruction.net/assets/web-app-theme/override.css

Make sure to include web-app-theme/override.css on your assets/stylesheets/application.css and run:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

before you push to heroku

Comment: Thanks, fixed that - and now I think what might be the problem is like you guys were saying earlier, the new css I got from the designer must have been copied from something that wasn't a plain text file - cause the older new css that I got it worked fine, this one does not, hopefully I get a new one which fixes the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I just got bit by "css assets not loading on Heroku".

My problem was that I forgot to compile the assets locally -- which is something you must do if a `public/assets/manifest.yml` is detected in your app. The presence of this file tells Heroku that you are handling asset compilation yourself and will **not** attempt to compile your assets.

See [Rails 3.1 on Heroku Cedar](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar#the_asset_pipeline)